# Where are screenshots taken in Overwatch on PC stored?

Tags: pc, overwatch

Looking through my file explorer to find screenshots I took in-game and can't seem to find them in the program files folder. Where are the Overwatch screenshots I take in-game stored in my hdd or sdd?

Comment: What's the default key to take a screenshot in Overwatch?

Comment: @MadMAxJr if you have a different question...

Comment: Nevermind, found it in another question.  It's the Print Screen key.  I'm too used to steam using F12 for everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find your screenshots at the following path:

> C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Overwatch\ScreenShots\Overwatch

Alternatively, some users may find their screenshots stored at:

> C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Overwatch\Screenshots\GameClientApp

Comment: Alternatively, you can enter `%UserProfile%/Documents/Overwatch/ScreenShots/Overwatch` into the Explorer bar.